# Django ORM - join a lot of tables by user_id

Tags: python, django, join, orm

I have about 5 tables with user foreign key, i.e.:

```
class Passport(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

Also, classes like UserProfile, Company, UserOptions, NotifySettings, etc. I need to get dict with joined values for user-summary page. Also i need to join to this union this summary stats:

```
rent_sums = WriteOff.objects.filter(created_at__range=(rent_start, rent_finish), write_off_type='rent').values('user').\
                annotate(rent_amount=Sum('amount')).order_by()
```

How can i do it without manualy update of a result dict?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by executing a [custom SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) from django but the main problem I see here is the way the models are been handled, it would be a lot easier if you mixed all this user foreign keys to be in the UserProfile, for example:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = fields.OneToOneField(User)
    company = fields.ForeignKey(Company)
    options = fields.ForeignKey(Options)
    notification_settings = fields.ForeignKey(NotifySettings)
    ...
```

This way you can use the ORM django brings with more ease. In my opinion it would be faster for you to create a migration instead of this huge query.